# Automating digital signature for dotm (word templates)

Tags: command-line, build-automation, digital-signature, pfx, word-template

Internally many developers work on customized word templates.  When we ship the code, we would like to add digital signatures (pfx) to the vb code or to the dotm templates.   Ideally, we would like to add this step to the build script.  Signcode/Signtool do not sign dotm file types.  I am wondering if there are other alternatives.  Currently I am considering this [System.IO.Packaging.PackageDigitalSignatureManager](http://www.jeff.wilcox.name/2010/03/vsixcodesigning/) and this [Set-AuthenticodeSignature](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849819.aspx), hoping they can be modified to support dotm files.

Since, dotm files can be signed via VB, I assume they can be digitally signed.  Is there any way to automate the signing of digital signatures for dotm files?

(I've read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2422508/sign-a-word-vba-project-file-via-command-line-or-other-form-of-automation) and related SO questions, hoping there are other solutions.)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the signtool to sign .dotm if you install [Microsoft Office Subject Interface Packages for Digitally Signing VBA Projects](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/confirmation.aspx?id=56617).

(See also: [Is it possible to sign a Excel VBA project including timestamp?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56808404/is-it-possible-to-sign-a-excel-vba-project-including-timestamp))